# Kafka Connect ensure ordering

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to use Mongo change stream to push change events from mongoDB into kafka Topic using *Kafka Connect*.
The good news is:

- Kafka maintain ordering inside a partition.
- Mongo maintain ordering using global clock.

But, what about the middle? what about kafka connect? does it maintain Ordering? how does that ordering works? I couldn't find any place where they say that kafka maintain ordering.

Here is a scenario:

- in Mongo - Update user Bob to be Authorized
- in Mongo - Update user bob Role to be Unauthorized

Then, assuming I have network latency and my kafka connect is a **cluster** of [kafka connect - Mongo Source](https://www.confluent.io/hub/mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb) (multiple instances), can this scenario happened (ordering matters):

- Got event to update bob to **Unauthorized**
- Got event to update bob to **authorized**

Or, if Mongo change stream is synced with kafka connect (somehow) and the above scenario will never happens, alternatively, the *"produce to kafka"* stage of [kafka connect - Mongo Source](https://www.confluent.io/hub/mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb) might get out of sync due to network latency and kafka might saves Unauthorized first, and later will save the Authorized message.

Note, I say this all might happens due to the fact that [kafka connect - Mongo Source](https://www.confluent.io/hub/mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb) is not just 1 instance, it can work as a cluster. and they do not say anything in the documentation that ensure the ordering in kafka the same as it was produced in mongodb change stream.

Comment: If ordering is so important, do you have the option of writing to Kafka directly from the source app?

Comment: From the answer I can only guess that the order is not maintained between mongo stream and kafka connect, right? when updating mongo, I can't also write directly into kafka because it's not an app that makes the changes, it sometimes happens directly from mongodb. In any case, it's not super important, it's just a missing information in kafka connect. The docs should say if it maintain the order of mongo change stream. (or maybe not?)

Comment: It's down to the implementation of the connector AFAIK, rather than Kafka Connect per se.

Answer (score 0):

If you maintain a deterministic production of the event ( not round robin partition assignment strategic )

and also set

```
{
"producer.override.max.in.flight.requests.per.connection": "1"
}
```

then the order at production will be preserved.